# How to assign a gesture recognizer to a collection?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uigesturerecognizer, iboutletcollection

My goal is to simply send the correct `button.titleLabel.text` to the handleLongPress function of my view controller. This is my function:

```
- (IBAction)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                          initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
    lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 1.0;
    [self setUserIntendsToChangeUIsoTheUIisLockedUntilUserSelection:YES];
    NSLog(@"sender? %@", sender);
    if ([sender.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        self.myButton = (UIButton *)sender.view;
        NSLog(@"!!!!! %@", self.myButton.titleLabel.text);
        [self.view addSubview:self.scrollPickerView];     
    }

}
```

This is my storyboard of which I have created a referencing outlet collection of buttons "H", "Cl", "C" etc etc.

[image]

Each button does respond to the `UILongPressGesture`, however the logged message `NSLog(@"!!!!! %@", self.myButton.titleLabel.text);` always references the same UIButton "C", even if I hold a different button. What have I done wrong? How can I get each button to send its title to the handleLongPress function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into this before. In Interface Builder, you only have 1 `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`. You need a separate `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`s for each view. What you should see in Interface Builder is a long row of `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` icons on the bottom bar.

As a side note:

```
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                          initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
    lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 1.0;
```

is wasted code. You create a new variable and do nothing with it.